# SAS programming : Convert Exponential value to numeric value in SAS

Tags: sas

How to convert exponential(for eg. 3.22254e2, 3.24456545e-3) values to numeric format(322.254,0.00324456545) in SAS. I am getting the source as varchar from a file and need to store the same in oracle as number format.

I need to read from a file(csv) so When i tried to do the same i get the result(b) as null.

My code:

```
data work.exp_num ; 
infile 'exp_number.csv'
      lrecl = 256
      delimiter = '~'
      dsd
      missover
      firstobs = 2; 
; 
attrib a length = $300
  format = $32.
  informat = $32.; 
input a ; 
run; 

data test;  
set work.exp_num;  
b=input(a,32.16);  
run;
```

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard informat  w.d .
Here you got an example:

```
data test;  
  a='3.24456545e-3'; output;  
  a='3.22254e2'; output;  
run;  

data erg;  
  set test;  
  b=input(a,32.16);  
run;
```